# Flame or fire with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, effect

is there any flame or fire effect with jquery in the net ?
(for both side of my site with devil between them)

i googled it with no results ...

thanks for answer

best regards

Comment: not sure what ur getting at here...

Comment: @Neal, at the moment he is getting at having his question closed.

Comment: @Darin i know, i am a part of it

Comment: [text-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/) should prove a delightful alternative to jquery!

Comment: For a close reason, it is overly broad, and not really a programming issue when on a web page.  What you want is an animated graphic of some kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet will probably be a transparent background image of flames.